# Swift Firebase Save/Update multiple parents with the same child values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of strings which is the "uid's" of users. I am trying to append data/children to these multiple "uid's". Adding children or updating children to individual parents/users is easy and I understand how to do it. The problem is that this array can either contain 1 uid or 50 uid's. Is it possible for me to take these uid's and then update them with the same value? I am unsure what code to provide since I am just trying everything to attack this.

With the code below, this is me send a message to other users.

**Array of uid strings**

```
var data = [String]()
```

**Sample code of me sending a message to 2 users, just wanted to provide something here to show I know how to update/save data**

```
private func sendMessageWithProperties(_ properties: [String: Any]) {
    let businessRef = Database.database().reference().child("Business Group Chats Messages").child((group?.uid)!).child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Business Group Chats Messages").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child((group?.businessName)!)
    let businesChildRef = businessRef.childByAutoId()
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
    let fromID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let timeStamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    var value:[String: Any] = ["fromId" : fromID, "timeStamp" : timeStamp, "name": self.loggedInUserData?["name"] as? String]

    properties.forEach { (k,v) in
        value[k] = v
    }

    childRef.updateChildValues(value) { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
            return
        }

        Database.database().reference().child("Business Group Chats").child((self.group?.uid)!).child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["last message" : childRef.key!, "timestamp" : timeStamp, "businessName":(self.group?.businessName)!])

        Database.database().reference().child("Business Group Chats").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child((self.group?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["last message" : childRef.key!, "timestamp" : timeStamp])

        self.inputContainerView.inputTextField.text = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is me taking that array of "uid's" and then pulling and printing that I can access each "uid" through a array of strings. Allowing me to access, now I can append data to each.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            self.businessUID = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                for item in dict {
                    let json = JSON(item.value)
                    let businessUid = json["uid"].stringValue
                    for uid in self.data {
                        if uid == businessUid {
                            //print(uid)
                            self.businessessuids = uid
                            print(self.businessessuids)

                            Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child(self.businessessuids).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                                print(snapshot)
                                print("Trying to pull data from multiple strings right here this shoudld work")
                            })
                            print("printing the values to match with the string UID's")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("does not exist")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is this an answer? The original question is a bit unclear since it was asking about an array of uid strings and this answer doesn’t seem to be related to that question.

Comment: Yeah what you gave me before was correct I am just trying to manipulate the data and outputs a bit